# Confusion about "picking values of $x$", partial fraction decomposition

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

One of the methods of decomposing a fraction and finding the constants, $A, B, C,$ etc., is to "pick values of $x$". For example, to find $A$ and $B$ of $${{3x}\over(x-1)(x+2)} = {A\over(x-1)} + {B\over(x+2)}$$

$${{3x}} = {A(x+2)} + {B(x-1)} $$

one is supposed to pick values of $x$. To find $A$, one would pick $x=1$, and then $A=1$. To find $B$, one would pick $x=-2$, and then $B=2$.

I am having a hard time understanding the rationale behind this method. It looks like we are trying to pick values of $x$ that will cancel out the other constant. Are these the only values that could be picked, or could any values theoretically be picked, but they fail to cancel out the other constant?

For example, once I find out that $A=1$ by picking $x=1$, could I then say ${{3x}} - {(x+2)}= {B(x-1)}$ and then solve for $B$ by picking out any value of $x$? Or am I only allowed to pick $x=-2$? If so, why?

Comment: Take $x=0$ and $x = -1$ for example then you get $0=2A-B$ and $-3=A-2B$ and solving this system of equations you also get $A = 1,B = 2$ so the choices for $x$ are often the roots because they are easier to work with but it doesn't restrict you in anyway.

Comment: Aside: the method is apparently known as the [Heaviside cover-up method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pick any value of $x$ you like, but if you don't pick those special values then you will end up with one equation in 2 variables $A$ and $B$. So then you'll have to pick two such values of $x$ and then solve a simultaneous system of two equations in two variables, as opposed to two separate equations in one variable.  You would still get the same answer, because the partial fraction decomposition is unique. But it is more work.

Comment: So the answer in my example it that I can't "double dip", meaning I can't pick $x=1$ to find $A=1$, and then within that same equation pick a different value for $x$ to find $B$. Is that correct?

Comment: Of course you can. That's the whole point. The equation holds for all values of $x$, so you can choose as many different values of $x$ as you like. But you only need 2 values here because there are only two unknowns ($A$ and $B$) to solve for.

Comment: Wow, I just tried that with many different values of $x$, and they all did indeed return $B=2$. I guess I was wondering why this is different from some generic equation such as $5x=A$, where different values of $x$ would return different values of $A$, but now I see that this is the whole point of the unique constants in partial fraction decomposition. This has helped my understanding greatly, much thanks!